# Сложение строк с одинаковыми идентификатором. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input, условия

Есть не фиксированное количество строк в таблице. В каждой строке есть 2 столбца

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столбцы разбиты на группы. Группы меняют первую цифру идентификатора. У каждой строки уникальный идентификатор. В одной группе может быть разное количество строк (от 1 до 50).

Необходимо реализовать следующую логику. При вводе цифры (именно цифры) в столбец "Неделя начала" должно извлекаться время из соседнего столбца и складываться со временем где идентификаторы начала недели равен введённом.

Т.е., есть введённые данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должны получаться данные:

1: 7

5: 5

7: 1

9: 4

23: 6

53: 7

Если был пропущен идентификатор, то он должен заменяться нулём (т.е., в примере 2-4,6,8,10-22,24-52: 0

Введённые идентификаторы начала недели идут по порядку. Начинаются от 1 и заканчиваются 200.

Знаю, что нужно создать массив размерностью 200 элементов, делать проверку на ввод в цикле и использовать событие input. Однако, не представляю, как забрать число из textbox'а и label'а и соотнести их, если количество строк в одной группе практически везде разное и количество групп не ограничено (в примере 2 группы, в каждой из которых по 5 строк. Однако, в реальности может быть и не 5 строк, а от 1 до 100. Аналогично и с группами).

Я не прошу написать код. Мне нужно понять, как можно соотнести информацию из 2-ух столбцов. Как javascript должен понять, что был произведён ввод в textbox (input), который в id содержит ключевое слово 'week'.

P.S. на выходе Textbox (input) имеет такой вид

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PPContent$week_1_1" type="text" 
id="MainContent_PPContent_week_1_1" class="week" data-column="1" 
data-row="1" style="width:100%">
```

a Label (span)

```
<span id="MainContent_PPContent_time_1_1" class="time" 
 data-columns="1" data-row="1">1</span>
```

Comment: Нашёл, как сделать проверку на то, что id содержит ключевое слово week  `$("input[id*='week']").val("It's week");` https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Gp4.png

Comment: решить за тебя домашку?

Comment: @norbornen Это не домашка. Решать ничего не нужно. Я пытаюсь разобраться, как отследить, что пользователь ввёл число, забрать это число и число из соседнего столбца. Нужны именно операции. Всё остальное, что написано лишь уточнение ситуации, для которой мне нужен данный функционал!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var list_inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('week');
var list_span = document.getElementsByClassName('time');
var txt = document.getElementById('infotxt');

[].forEach.call(list_inputs, function (el) {
   el.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
      txt.innerHTML = null;
      var arr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < list_inputs.length; i++) {
         if (list_inputs[i].value != "") {
            col = list_inputs[i].dataset.column;
            row = list_inputs[i].dataset.row;
            for (var j = 0; j < list_span.length; j++) {
               if (list_inputs[i].dataset.column == list_span[j].dataset.column && list_inputs[i].dataset.row == list_span[j].dataset.row) {
                  if (arr[list_inputs[i].value] == null) arr[list_inputs[i].value] = 0;
                  
                  arr[list_inputs[i].value] += parseInt(list_span[j].textContent);
                  break;
               }
            }
         }
      }
      for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
         if (arr[i] == null) arr[i] = 0; 
         txt.innerHTML += arr[i] + "<br>";
      }
   });
});
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
   margin: 10px 5px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<td><input style="width:80px" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PPContent$week_1_1" type="text" id="MainContent_PPContent_week_1_1" class="week" data-column="1" data-row="1" style="width:100%"></td><td><span id="MainContent_PPContent_time_1_1" class="time" data-column="1" data-row="1">1</span></td>
<td><input style="width:80px" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PPContent$week_1_2" type="text" id="MainContent_PPContent_week_1_2" class="week" data-column="2" data-row="1" style="width:100%"></td><td><span id="MainContent_PPContent_time_1_2" class="time" data-column="2" data-row="1">2</span></td>
<td><input style="width:80px" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PPContent$week_1_3" type="text" id="MainContent_PPContent_week_1_3" class="week" data-column="3" data-row="1" style="width:100%"></td><td><span id="MainContent_PPContent_time_1_3" class="time" data-column="3" data-row="1">3</span></td>
<br>
<td><input style="width:80px" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PPContent$week_2_1" type="text" id="MainContent_PPContent_week_2_1" class="week" data-column="1" data-row="2" style="width:100%"></td><td><span id="MainContent_PPContent_time_2_1" class="time" data-column="1" data-row="2">1</span></td>
<td><input style="width:80px" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PPContent$week_2_2" type="text" id="MainContent_PPContent_week_2_2" class="week" data-column="2" data-row="2" style="width:100%"></td><td><span id="MainContent_PPContent_time_2_2" class="time" data-column="2" data-row="2">2</span></td>
<td><input style="width:80px" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PPContent$week_2_3" type="text" id="MainContent_PPContent_week_2_3" class="week" data-column="3" data-row="2" style="width:100%"></td><td><span id="MainContent_PPContent_time_2_3" class="time" data-column="3" data-row="2">3</span></td>
<br>
<span id="infotxt"></span>
```